# Multiple imputation of categorical variables in large data set

Tags: r, imputation

I have a data set with 4000+ observations of 130 variables, and about half of those variables have missingness. I'm trying to use this code, which creates five imputed data sets:

```
mice(data_frame, method = c(rep("pmm", 130)), m = 5, maxit = 5)
```

However, this code only imputes on my numeric variables and does nothing to my categorical variables; it just ignores the categorical variables.

I thought maybe the problem was that I was using Predictive Mean Matching for everything and that it was meant for numeric data only, but I tested using this on a smaller data set and it seems to be able to impute categorical data just as well as numeric data when using PMM. So I'm stumped about why the code is just ignoring my categorical variables. I tried "logreg" and "polyreg" on a few of those variables, but they still just get ignored.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem: my variables were `character` class rather than `factor` class, and the MICE algorithm ignores character classes. Once I converted all of the variables into factors, the code above worked fine. I used `sapply` on the variables that needed to become factors to make things easier on myself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).